# How do I throw an exception for different classes in an interface?

Tags: java

I have a Vehicle interface. I want to make a class that tests different classes for speed. If a vehicle can not accelerate, it breaks down.

In the Vehicle interface, I have

```
public abstract void stop();
public abstract void accelerate(int rate);
public abstract void decelerate(int rate);
```

The Speed.java class I made is to test different vehicles that extend from Vehicle.java (Bicycle.java, SportsCar.java).

How would I make it so that it throws an exception saying that it is unable to accelerate using the same method for some of the vehicles I am testing?

Ex:
I want Car.Speed() to print "Accelerating..."
I want Bicycle.Speed() to throw an exception and break down.

Comment: You can declare it in the interface, or you can throw runtime exceptions?

Comment: @matt How would I do that? I'm new to Java so I'm not too technical when it comes to things like this.

Comment: @Daniel Please see [ask].  What have you tried?  Also be clear about what you want.  You're talking about 2 different things: throwing an exception, and printing a message.  Which one are you confused about?  And where should the exception be thrown?  It's not clear if the exception should be thrown in the `accelerate()` method or the `Speed()` method.  In fact, you don't even define the `Speed()` method in the interface, so there's a lot we're left guessing on here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have your `Vehicle` interface. You can either have the interface declare the exception.

```
public interface Vehicle{
    void stop() throws Exception;
    void accelerate(int rate);
    //public abstract void decelerate(int rate);
}
```

In this interface, stop is declared to throw an exception but accelerate does not.

```
public class Car implements Vehicle{
    public void stop() throws Exception{
        //we don't have to throw an exception, but we can.
    }
    public voic accelerate(){
        throw new RuntimeException("We can throw this from any method");
    }
}
```

In this way to call Car.stop the caller must handle an exception. In the body of stop we can throw an Exception or we don't have to.

For accelerate, we cannot throw an Exception because it is a checked exception. We can however throw a RuntimeException.

We cannot implement the interface and add an exception.

```
class Cart implements Vehicle{
    public void stop(){
        //this is ok.
    }
    public void accelerate() throws Exception{
        //not ok because it will not compile.
        //The exception will be hidden when the Cart is used as
        //a vehicle.
    }
}
```